# ejabberd xmlrpc configuration error

Tags: ejabberd

ejabberd version: 16.04
OS: CentOS 7

I followed this document to setup xmlrpc support and need some help to configure access control:
https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc

I was just trying to setup the simple config following the example: 
XML-RPC calls can execute any command, with any argument, and no authentication information must be provided.

Here is my config file .yml:

```
listen:
  -
    port: 4560
    module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
    maxsessions: 10
    timeout: 5000
```

Based on the document, I shouldn't need to do anything else.

Here is my client side java code:

```
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
URL url = new URL("http://myhost:4560/");
config.setServerURL(url);
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
client.setConfig(config);
String command = "status";
Map struct = new HashMap();
Object[] params = new Object[] { struct };
Object result = client.execute(command, params);
```

however, I got this error on both client side and server side log:

```
2016-05-17 22:37:00.553 [warning] <0.498.0>@ejabberd_xmlrpc:build_fault_response:386 Error -118
A problem '{error,account_unprivileged}' occurred executing the command status with arguments
[]
```

I tried to add admin username and password in the client configuration call and still failed.

I think I'm missing something very basic. Any help is appreciated.

--Nathan

Comment: I am having the same issue with the same version. However, I am using as a url with the format "http://myhost:4560/RPC2"

Comment: any luck resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This workis for me:

```
-
 port: 4560
 module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
 maxsessions: 10
 timeout: 5000
 access_commands: []
```

You have to specify access_comands to an empty list